# Adding class to element after page loads prevents click

Tags: jquery

I have a page that has an AJAX call. On response I add an class to one of the elements with .addClass

```
$("#cq div:first-child").addClass('curCat');
```

Later in my JS code I am trying to add a click function to that element, unfortunately it does not seem to react

```
$('.curCat').click(function() {
    $('#cq div').show();
});
```

I thought, that perhaps it was due to the fact that I added class after the DOM was loaded and tried using delegate() but to no avail.

Kinda lost at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `.live()`

```
$('.curCat').live('click', function() {
    $('#cq div').show();
    $(this).css('border-bottom','1px solid #ccc');
});
```

Comment: I believe `on()` is recommended in later versions of jQuery.

Comment: Wow, it di take care of the problem. Thanks.